# Java returns error "Cannot instantiate the type"

Tags: java

I got this error message when I try to init a new object.

```
Cannot instantiate the type Car
```

My code

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Car car = new Car(4,4,COUNTRY.MALAYSIA, Locale.ENGLISH, "150.00"); //error here
    }
}
```

Car.java

```
public abstract class Car implements Automobile {

    public int wheel;
    public int door;
    public COUNTRY country;
    public Locale locale;
    public String price;

    public Car(int w, int d, COUNTRY c, Locale l, String p){
        this.wheel = w;
        this.door = d;
        this.country = c;
        this.locale = l;
        this.price = p;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can not instantiate an abstract class. However you can create a child class of an abstract class and instantiate it instead.

Comment: remove `abstract` keyword to **Car** class as **abstract classes cannot be instantiated.**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Car is an Abstract class you cannot create an instance of it.

```
public abstract class Car implements Automobile
```

you can potentially do something like

```
public class FordFocus extends Car
```

keep in mind that you will need to call the super constructor, but then you will be able to create an instance of the FordFocus car type

Answer (score 4):

Your class `Car` is an abstract class and you cannot create an instance of an abstract class.

**Solution 1**
Instead you need to create a concrete class that extends your class `Car` and then you can create an instance of that concrete class.

**Solution 2**
Remove abstract from your `Car` class declaration (But I think you don't want to do that).

Answer (score 0):

[`Documentation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) states that

> An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.

So reference `Car car` is supported, but object `new Car();` is not supported.